# Alternative of dreamweaver and adobe software?

Tags: dreamweaver, photoshop

can any one tell me best alternatives of all Adobe software because I tried PhotoScape in place of Photoshop and SeaMonkey in place of Dreamweaver

Comment: This question should be closed since it's strongly based on opinions and can not get an objective answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used aptana for a while, and notepad++ as a dreamweaver replacement but there is no general replacement, each app has its own set of features which the user uses or doesn't use.
As for photoshop, coreldraw and paintshop pro were the main competitors or Gimp as an opensource replacement but nothing seems to beat photoshop imo.